# Programmatically setColor,font to Textviews

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a list view with 3 items in each list view item using two separate .'xml's.

1) list_view.xml

```
 <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ListView">
 </ListView>
```

2) list_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Text here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/seperator"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="000"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="$"
        android:id="@+id/prefix"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/price"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, I have created a list view with all the items using a 'SimpleAdapter'. Now I want to access the items in the list view (textView, separator,...) and change the color, size etc programmatically.

Here is the code of my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    public SimpleAdapter mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        //background color
        list.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

        TextView itemText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        itemText.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //Dummy data
        //add all elements to map
        map.put("text", "click to edit0");
        map.put("seperator", "-");
        map.put("price", "100");
        // add map elements to list
        mylist.add(map);

        //add all elements to map
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("text", "click to edit1");
        map.put("seperator", "-");
        map.put("price", "102");
        //add all elements to map
        mylist.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("text", "click to edit2");
        map.put("seperator", "-");
        map.put("price", "104");
        mylist.add(map);

        //use adapter to set list items
        mList = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] {"text", "seperator", "price"}, new int[] {R.id.textView, R.id.seperator, R.id.price});
        list.setAdapter(mList);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

All worked fine until I tried to access the list view items and change them.
My code crashes and shows a null pointer exception at

```
TextView itemText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
itemText.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
```

I suspect this might be because I did not the setContentView to list_item.xml.
Is there a way to access the elements? If yes how?

Comment: could you post the exception log as well? thx

Answer (score 0):

for setting color follow the bellow code

```
String text = "<font color=#8469af>By tapping Checkout, you agree to our </font> <font color=#ffffff>terms.</font>";
    tvTerms.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: `TextView` has a method for setting color: `public void setTextColor (int color)` why bother using bulky HTML?

Comment: sorry...but it is actually for setting different colors for single textview

Answer (score 0):

when you try to call findviewbyid  you didnt create listitems yet so it returns null pointer

if you want to set type face with standart font use

```
 android:typeface="serif"
```

but if you insist do it programmatically
first get list items from list then

```
(TextView) list_item.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Talha pointed out the exception comes from the call on `findViewById` on `this` where your id textView does not exists, so it returns null

If you want to modify your list items programmatically you should implement your own adapter and apply your modifications in the [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method